# Can I run Dragon Ball Fighter Z with a GeForce 9800 1GB?

Tags: nvidia-geforce, geforce-experience

I still haven't upgraded my PC, so I'm wondering if it's possible to run Dragon Ball Fighter Z with the following configuration:

```
Intel core i5-2500 CPU 3.30 GHz
8GB RAM
GeForce 9800 GT 1GB
```

Has anyone been able to run this game on old graphic cards?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm wondering if it is possible to run Dragon Ball Fighter Z with the following configuration

It absolutely cannot run on the hardware you have.

[image]

[Source](https://store.steampowered.com/app/678950/DRAGON_BALL_FighterZ/)

> Has anyone been able to run this game on old graphic cards?

The hardware does not even come close to meeting the minimum requirements to run Dragon Ball Fighter Z.